# When input name is file[] the bind to IFormFile does not work. Dropzone + .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, dropzone

I'm trying to upload many files per request using dropzone and a web API using .Net Core.

To do so, we must configure Dropzone to send many files in one request using the uploadMultiple option. By default, dropzone sends one file per request. If you are to upload 10 files, it will make 10 requests. I don't want that.

When uploadMultiple is set to true, dropzone will append a [] to the name of the input. For instance, let's say that the name of the input is Files. When uploadMultiple is true, it becomes Files[].

To read the files in the .Net Core Web API, we just need to create a controller that receives a IList reading from form. Like this:

```
public ActionResult<MyResponse> Upload([FromForm] IList<IFormFile> Files)
```

**The problem**

The problem is the [] in the name. Dropzone sends the files under the name:

Files[0], 
Files[1]... File[N]

Then the bind in the .Net Core fails because it expects the name to be File. I've tried to change the binding name to be:

```
public ActionResult<MyResponse> Upload([FromForm(Name = "Files[]")] IList<IFormFile> Files)
```

But this didn't work then. When I've changed to:

```
public ActionResult<MyResponse> Upload([FromForm(Name = "Files[0]")] IList<IFormFile> Files)
```

It worked for the first entry of the array of files.

So what I'm looking for is a way to make the name pattern "File[any_number]" sent by Dropzone to bind in the IList of the .Net Core Web API.

Is there any way to achieve that?

So far, to solve this, I'm reading the files directly from the request. Like this:

```
var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
```

But I prefer to use the binding alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've found the solution.

It seems that the [FromForm(Name = "File")] can only receive a literal string and not a pattern. So there is nothing to do in the Web API end.

But we can change the way dropzone sends the files by removing the [] from the input name. Thanks to this issue:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/901

There is a hidden feature (not documented) that allows us to pass a function to the paramName option instead of a string. By doing this we override the dropzone behavior of adding a [] in the file name when multiple.

With that the files are sent like they usually would and the bind works naturally.